# For $T\colon V\to V$ every anti self-adjoint $T$ is orthogonally diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I know how to prove that every self-adjoint operator is orthogonally diagonalizable (using spectral the and Gram Schmidt process). But I am not sure how to apply to an anti self-adjoint operator. Can someone please help me write a proof for this?

Comment: If this is a complex space, then $iT$ is self-adjoint if $T$ is anti-self-adjoint.

Answer (score 0):

A skew-Hermitian (anti self-adjoint) operator $T$ is always [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator), meaning that it commutes with its adjoint: $T\, T^*=T^*\, T$ (just like a self-adjoint operator). A [variant of the spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices) says exactly that an operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space is normal if and only if it is orthogonally diagonalizable.